# Count Individual Columns Power BI

Tags: count, dax, row

I’m just trying to create a few simple pie charts using tables.

Below is something similar to what I’m working with just on a much higher scale (otherwise I’d just filter them out).

| code | name |
| --- | --- |
| 7B | Hugh |
| 7B. | mike |
| 6A | Sam |
| 8L. | Chris |
| 8L | Mandy |
| 8L. | Louise |
| 8L | Jack |
| 3A. | Bob |

I just want to be able to count how many occurances of Code are found within the table - e.g - 8L should be 4, 7B 2 and so forth.

The names can be completely ignored - I’ve just put them in for measure to make it look somewhat like a table plus I’m not sure if it makes much difference that there are around 20 columns within this table?

I’m sure it’s a very simple solution but it is just racking my brains.

I’ve tried to play around with a few count row formulas, just can’t seem to find the right one if this even is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

(Your data is a bit messy, but I assume that's from the copy & paste).

In your table, create a measure,

RowCount = COUNTROWS('Name of Table')

Then add a matrix to your design surface. Names goes on Rows and RowCount goes in the VALUES well. done. =)